Windows 11 & 11 Dual Boot - Show which OS to boot into on startup?
I recently moved an M.2 drive from my second PC to my primary PC. My primary PC already has a Windows 11 installation and so does the newly installed M.2. I would like to keep both installs and boot into the other OS whenever I want to.
The problem is, I can currently only change which OS to boot into when I am in the UEFI BIOS, which of course requires a full shutdown and going into the bios every time I want to switch. Quite annoying and time consuming.
I found articles which show a Windows screen with each OS listed and the possibility of automatically booting into one after a set amount of time. See: https://www.windowscentral.com/software-apps/windows-11/how-to-create-a-dual-boot-setup-on-windows-11
I believe this does not appear in my case as booth instances of Windows 11 have their own boot manager.
I removed the drive letter of the other Windows 11 installation in both instances as I wanted the instances of Windows to be as isolated from each other as possible, as I would like to use one for work and one for gaming, therefore no drive sharing etc. I believe this also means that bcdedit would also not work in my case.
Is it possible to have the OS selection appear in my case or would I need to reinstall the second instance of Windows 11? Or is there another way to have a OS selection appear outside of using the Windows boot manager?
To sum it up: I have 2 separate Windows 11 installs on 2 different drives. I want them to be separate and basically isolated from each other. This also means I don't want to use a VM. I am looking for a way to have the option of choosing the OS I want to boot into on startup, instead of going into the BIOS every time.

Boot managers only show up when you shut down or restart, same as your UEFI. There is the benefit with a boot manager of fewer key presses, but just note that you're still going to have to restart to get to the boot manager. Drive letters are stored/assigned in the OS, so removing a drive letter is not likely to be what you want to do. I'd recommend waiting for good answers here before trying anything further, to avoid doing something that will be harder to back out of.

You should add new entry windows in bcdedit. You can do this using Commandline or GUI. use some apps like BootIce, DiskGenius, EasyUEFI.  https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/bootice_64_bit.html

A complicating factor may be that Windows needs to be installed on a particular disk in the boot order, and so having Windows 1 on one disk, and Windows 2on a complete different disk, may not actually end up being possible EXCEPT unless you use the UEFI boot option. I may be wrong, but I do recall Windows having some requirements like this.

@John I would like to avoid VMs for this

@Mr.Key7 Access denied

what do you want like this?  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w-bvnzgqKnLwXkyc9o7UEfk3qZZk4C1J/view?usp=sharing

-@John It's been a long time since I installed multiple OS (win7,10,11, linuxs) but it doesn't make it slow.

@Mr.Key7 Yes something like this, just with both Windows 11 instances listed

-@cryseascr do it using litle app BootIce

@Mr.Key7 Unless I have missed a way, that seems not possible if I want to hide the drives, on which each OS is on, from each other.

I don't know exactly what you want.
If you want both windows entries to be displayed when booting, and you can choose one of them to run without needing to enter the bios settings, then you have to add a boot menu entry using the app.
